# Does it matter if a form has close called twice?

Tags: .net, winforms

Is it safe to call close on a form and then call close again on it. no other operations are being done with it after the first close.

my suspicion is that this is bad and it is effectively racing the GC to call the second close? (and winning 99.999% of the time so I'm not seeing any error)

Edit: to be clear this is IMHO a bug, but it is not currently causing any exception to be thrown. the problem is more how big an issue is it? should I fix the one I've found and move on because it's relatively benign, or should I review every form in the design to make sure there isn't any similar issue on the grounds that the lack of exception may depend on GC behaviour.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling it twice. You should add a code example where you are closing it twice or where you think it's being called twice. If it is disposed or null, I would expect an exception stating just that. If you're not getting an exception now, why worry about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second call isn't going to close the native window anymore, it's gone.  It will just call Dispose() again.  Which is fine, disposing an object multiple times is supported in all .NET classes.

None of this has anything to do with the garbage collector, clearly you still have a reference to the form object or you wouldn't have been able to call Close().  Don't keep this reference around forever or you'll leak the form object.  It is otherwise dead and can't be revived.  Referencing members of that form object tends to throw ObjectDisposedException.

Comment: right, so nothing bad will happen to the unmanaged resources but the second close may throw an exception I think this answers my question

Comment: I think some of my confusion here was the msdn on form.close description of the condition for ObjectDisposedException

Answer (score 1):

It should be fixed, but it might not be a big priority. The problem is that it MAY cause exceptions or odd behavior in the future, after modifications to the application or when a newer version of .net is used. In other words, it's not safe.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Close()` on a form that's already closed suggests some design issues you should rethink. However, I'm not aware of any problems this causes.

You could use Reflector to see exactly what close does. But I'm pretty sure it checks if the form is actually open.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sure way to know what the GC is doing. If you have a form and call `Close()` on it twice and there is not an exception thrown (either Null or Disposed), then where is the problem? There would not be any 'racing' condition.

My question would be, "why are there 2 calls to Close() in the first place?"